# A definition which is nonequivalent to that of a covering space

Tags: algebraic-topology, examples-counterexamples, covering-spaces

A typo in my lecture notes made me wonder if these definitions are actually equivalent. Let $\tilde X \xrightarrow{p} X$ be continuous and surjective.

1. (actual definition of covering spaces) For any $x \in X$ we find $U$ a neighborhood of $x$ such that $p^{-1}(U) = \bigsqcup\limits_{i \in I} U_i$ ($U_i \subseteq \tilde X$ open and pairwise disjoint) such that $U_i$ is homeomorphic to $U$ via $p$.
2. Same as before, only instead of $U_i$ homeomorphic to $U$ via $p$, we just require that $p|_{U_i}$ be injective and $U_i$ be homeomorphic to $U_j$ for any $i, j \in I$.

My intuition says these two are very likely not equivalent (of course, the first implies the second). However, is there an example of a $p$ which satisfies (2) but not (1)?

Comment: Let $\tilde{X}$ be any discrete space, let $X$ be non-discrete, and let $p : \tilde{X} \to X$ be any map...

Comment: Think of a constant map from a connected space to a point.

Comment: In (2), do you also want $\left.p\right\rvert_{U_j}$ to be injective for all $j$? I think it will still be non-equivalent, but otherwise it sounds a bit silly.

Comment: @Gae.S. Yes, that would make for a more interesting question, as I see now by what Minkowski said. I will edit the question.

Comment: @rosecabbagedragon Although now that I think about it there's still the fundamental triviality of considering a bijective continuous function $p$ which is not a homeomorphism.

Comment: You're right. I should ask the metaquestion of whether this question can be made interesting.

Comment: And you must have **open** $U_i$.

Comment: A naive counterexample would be the inclusion of a line in the plane, where $I$ is either empty or a singleton. However this is not a covering map.